# syntax error on linux division and multipication

Tags: linux

I am trying to calculate 20% of `a` where `a` is input by the user.

```
echo "Please enter your basic salary"
read a
#HRA
b=`expr (20 / 100)\* $a)`|bc

echo HRA is:$b
```

What's wrong in this expression, which is generating an error message?

Comment: Perhaps including the actual error message might be useful...

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you want to just pass the expression into bc for evaluation, so use echo rather than expr.

Secondly, the order of evaluation you have is going to calculate 20/100 as an integer first, which will be 0, then multiple the salary by that, resulting in 0. Reordering the calculation will resolve that.

So the following should work:

```
echo "Please enter your basic salary"
read a
#HRA
b=`echo $a " * 20 / 100"|bc`

echo HRA is:$b
```

Alternatively, if you prefer to use expr rather than bc, you can escape the problem characters to make this work:

```
echo "Please enter your basic salary"
read a
#HRA
b=`expr $a \* 20 \/ 100`

echo HRA is:$b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `let` operator also in `bash`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please enter your basic salary"
read a
let b=$a*20/100
echo HRA is:$b
```